# Repeatedly convolving two large arrays [python]

Tags: python, kernel, convolution

I'm working in Python.

In a Monte Carlo scheme, I want to repeatedly convolve an image (of let's say 500x500 pixels) with a varying kernel, of between 50x50 and 200x200 pixels.

I'm using `convolve_fft` from `astropy.convolution` to compute the convolution.

Right now, the whole scheme is prohibitively slow. Odds are the answer to this question is simply 'no, there is not', but is there something I can do to speed things along?

Comment: Have you tried a parallel approach on Monte Carlo? This might be a good reading for you: https://wiseodd.github.io/techblog/2016/06/13/parallel-monte-carlo/

Comment: Yeah, it's fully parallel. If I was doing this for one object, it'd take a bit of time but it'd be fine. The problem is that I'm doing it for hundreds.

Comment: Have you configured your convolve_fft to use pyfwfft3? That can give quite a good speedup. You can also do half ffts in some cases, which would give another factor of two.